# How to save a custom View's state in a RecyclerView in a dynamically added fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, fragmenttransaction, android-savedstate

**TL;DR :** I cannot differentiate the `RecyclerView`'s call to `onBindViewHolder` when it is recycling a `View` or replacing the `Fragment`.

I did spend a lot of time looking for answers here on SO, but nothing worked in the end. What it did do is teach me the answer probably is in using `savedInstanceState`, but I did not manage to successfully use it.

**Structure :**

- MainFragment

  - MainView
  - SwitchFragmentButton

In the `MainView` is a `FrameLayout`, which is used to hold a `Fragment`.

The first `Fragment` doesn't matter, but the second `Fragment` is an `OverviewFragment`, whose structure is :

- OverviewFragment

  - RecyclerView

    - CustomItemView

      - TextView
      - ChangeTextColorButton
      - DeleteItemButton
      - ...
  - AddItemButton

I am using a `RecyclerView` because the list needs to be horizontal and that's the easiest way I found to do it.

**Desired behavior :**

I want the color change to be kept when I click on the button twice (to change fragment then get back on it) but not when I delete the item from the list then add it again.

**Problem :**

The color is either always or never kept. Using `onBindViewHolder` in the `RecyclerView`'s Adapter to set the text color does not allow me to differentiate if the bind is coming from the fragment replacement (where I would restore the changed color) or the view recycling (where I would not restore it)

**Code :**

The `SwitchFragmentButton`'s `OnClickListener` calls the `MainView`'s method

```
void switchFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentManager fm = mainFragment.getChildFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.mainView_fragment_slot, fragment);
    ft.commit();
}
```

Here's how the color is managed (simplified) :

```
public class CustomItemView extends FrameLayout {
    private TextView textView;
    private int color;
    /* other attributes */

    public CustomItemView(/* any default constructor */) {
        super(/* args */);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        inflate(getContext, R.layout.custom_item_view, this);
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.customItemView_text_view);
        ChangeTextColorButton ctcButton = /* ... */;
        /* other views */

        ctcButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick() {
                setColor(getColorWithDialogAndAll());
            }
        }

        resetColor();
    }

    public void resetColor() {
        setColor(0xff0000ff);
    }

    public void setColor(int color) {
        this.color = color;
        textView.setTextColor(color);
    }

    /* other methods */
}
```

And here is the `RecyclerView`'s `Adapter` definition :

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
    private List<MyItem> myItemList = new LinkedList<>();

    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        MyViewHolder viewHolder = (MyViewHolder) holder;
        //this is called in both situations
        viewHolder.customItemView.resetColor();
    }

    /* other methods */

    private class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        CustomItemView cutsomItemView;

        /* constructor, calling super() and setting the attribute */
    }
}
```

`MyItem` here is the core item of CustomItemView (every MyItem its CustomItemView and every CustomItemView has its MyItem)

**Notes :**

`minSdkVersion` : 19.

### EDIT :

Thanks to @goldenb, the problem has been narrowed and two solutions appeared.

**Solution 1 :**

Instead of replacing the fragments, add them all then show/hide them.

```
void switchFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentManager fm = mainFragment.getChildFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.hide(currentFragment);
    ft.show(R.id.mainView_fragment_slot, fragment);
    ft.commit();

    currentFragment = fragment;
}
```

This solution somehow works but isn't a real fix to the problem. It avoids deleting the `Fragments`, so the state is kept.

However, my question is about how to save then restore the `Fragment`'s state, so I can't accept this as an answer.

**Solution 2 :**

Override `OverviewFragment#onPause` to save the state, and restore it in `OverviewFragment#onCreate`.

This solution seems plausible, I am currently exploring it. It however needs some restructuration in my project to relocate the data from the `CustomItemView` to the `MyAdapter`, so it's going to take some time.

Comment: Man, your question is interesting but unclear to me. I think you should try to boil it down to : 1. A minimal hierarchy, stripping out non-interesting childs and non-interesting layers 2. A clear statement of what’s the problem.

Comment: As a quick response, note that it’s the *view* responsibility to restore its own state, not yours. Override your custom view's onSaveInstanceState() and onRestoreInstanceState() methods to save and restore its color.

Comment: @natario 1. What child would you remove ? I tried to give a good idea of the context.
2. I reworded that, see if it helps.
3. Wouldn't overriding these methods cause the recycled views to also restore an unwanted color?

Answer (score 0):

You may use savedInstancestate or RestoresavedInstancestate in the Activity or be using shared preferences in fragments to store data and extracts data when you call back that fragments

Comment: The Activity isn't affected here. When I switch fragments, the Activity's onSaveInstanceState(..) and onRestoreInstanceState(..) aren't called.

Answer (score 0):

If it is acceptable to you opting for not destroying the View hierarchy at all:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager()
// Or: FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager()
fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    .remove(fragment1)
    .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment2)
    .show(fragment3)
    .hide(fragment4)
    .commit();
```

Hope this helps after all the edits!

Comment: Didn't change a thing... except that my code is a bit cleaner now. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Irhala look at the code, are you doing transaction.addToBackStack(null);  before commit? When you later call FragmentManager.popBackStack() waht happens?

Comment: That's exactly what I did. I don't know much about addToBackStack() and popBackStack(), but I guess all popBackStack will do is remove(new) then add(old), which I was doing manually before. Nothing seems to have changed.

Comment: I think I know what your problem is, I will update the answer , just give me a few minutes

Comment: @Irhala check the answer update and tell me if it works

Comment: It looks like it should work, but how am I supposed to handle the list with this ? Maybe I should remove the data from the customView and put it in the adapter instead ?

Comment: @Irhala these are two separate issues you should not mix: fragment state and your recyclerview operation.  your adapter should be able to create ViewHolders and Bind them whenever necessary, before and after show/hide

Comment: @Irhala this is another question but the data should as a rule of thumb, be placed on the dataSet in the adapter. this way, during onBind(...) you can always get the item from the data list based on position, and make all decisions about view changes / color even set onclicklisteners etc

Comment: Tried it, it somehow works but is like putting a child band-aid on a forest to say sorry for the cut trees. The problem isn't resolved, only bypassed, and  will show up every time I want to manage my fragments

Comment: @Irhala then you must edit/change your question because if what you want is to switch fragments keeping state, you already got this.
Another issue is with your binding (i agree with you that you should change how you are doing it)

Comment: @Irhala  if you need any more help, I could probably  help more effectively if I ran the code and debugged it, it's a bit more work but I could do it if you share the full code or repo